# wrong numbers received by arduino via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to send some numbers from my smart phone to my Arduino via Bluetooth. I have connected everything right and it works perfect, but *my problem is with sending negative numbers*.

For example, I try to send -173 (bin: `11111111 01010011`) it receives 83 (bin: `00000000 01010011`) which is the second byte only. I have tried to use long or double or signed int instead of integers, but I have failed.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library

SoftwareSerial Genotronex(51, 11); // RX, TX
int ledpin=53; // led on D13 will show blink on / off
BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Genotronex.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Genotronex.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ..");
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   if (Genotronex.available()){
    BluetoothData=Genotronex.read();
    Serial.print(BluetoothData);
   }

}
delay(100);// prepare for next data ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Serial.write instead of Serial.print.
I have a similar device and it works very well with Serial.write

Answer (score 0):

Reason is because print works with all kinds of different types and write only works with byte type (in C that is an unsigned value from 0..255).